# VLC Time Slider not working

Tags: video, vlc, time, interface

I have a problem with my VLC on ubuntu 16.04, my vlc time slider can't be clicked. When i hover the cursor on it my cursor icon change to resize icon. any answer apreciated
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyfYo.png)

Comment: I have just encountered this issue myself on Ubuntu 16.04 and VLC 3.0.2 built from tarball with both, default Qt 5.5.1 and custom Qt 5.9.5 build. I have rebuilt VLC from latest git commit in master branch (commit hash 98bdfe4, it reports version 4.0.0-dev) and it does not have this problem. Incidentally, I also finally have VA-API on Intel working O_O.